# Remove any indication to the indication tag?

Tags: discussion, meta, burninate-request

I believe the [indication](/questions/tagged/indication) tag should be burninated. The term itself is too broad and doesn't really fit as a meta tag.

With 12 questions only it should be simple even for one or two users, just want to get some consensus first or see if anyone objects. Your thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, it's a typical meta tag. Let it burn!

Comment: @Glorfindel thanks, let's wait a bit and start rolling soon. :-)

Comment: I have no indication this is wrong ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing the tag from the last 5 questions, I agree [indication](/questions/tagged/indication) tag indicates *too* many different things, and as such, not particularly useful.

The fact that searching [indication](/questions/tagged/indication) returning 0 questions indicates that the tag has been burninated!

[image: Trogdor]

Comment: In case somebody wants to check whether some of the questions where the tag was removed should also have some additional tags, here is a simple query which should return those questions: [Posts which had given tag in the past](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/927958/posts-which-had-given-tag-in-the-past-including-current-tags?tagName=indication). (Although looking at the front page, I see that in several post other tags have been added to replace this one in the process of the tag removal.)